# Is a SQLite3 database file locked globally while writing to temp tables?

Tags: database, multithreading, sqlite, transactions, locking

I have an application with different threads that all access a common SQLite3 database file. All threads create their own connection handle plus some temporary table using a statement like `CREATE TEMP TABLE FileCacheTemp AS ...`.

Now I perform a long-running transaction block into the temp table on one thread using `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, followed by multiple `INSERT INTO FileCacheTemp ...` statements and finalized with a `COMMIT`. Will SQLite3 lock only read/writes to the thread-local, non-shared, in-memory temp table or will it lock the whole database file for all threads?

I am using SQLite3 version 3.13.0 with default journal mode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is right. SQLlite is not efficient enough for concurrency and locks the complete database. Please refer the below statement from one of the SQLlite docs:

> Locking Support for SQLite The SQLite database has very limited
>   support for concurrency. This has implications for the default locking
>   strategy, hit list behavior, and transaction length.
>
> When a READ lock is placed on a record or table (for example, when
>   retrieving records), SQLite locks the whole database, preventing other
>   applications from inserting, updating, or deleting records anywhere in
>   the database.

Link: https://unifaceinfo.com/docs/0906/Uniface_Library_HTML/ulibrary/SLE_Locking_B33EF9F17B6F4EDE8821F4EA355D52B2.html

Comment: Unfortunately the SQLite documentation on [locking](https://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) is not specific whether this also applies to attached or in-memory databases.